# What RAM could I use?

Tags: memory

I have an Asus Model CG-5270 with 8GB-DDR2-RAM-240 Pin (4x2gb) and would like to upgrade it to 16GB.

I've been told I could do it but am unsure about the type of RAM I should be looking for other than a 4GB-DDR2.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Go to Asus website and search for your model there.

Comment: It is very unlikely your system based on its age will support 16GB.  My educated guess after looking up hundreds of device specifications that use DDR2 memory the maximum size module most system supported was 4GB. The fact you only have two slots indicates this is highly likely.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications from that computer states that it can support a `maximum of 16 GB RAM`, with a form factor of `DIMM 240 pin`. It does not state whether it can use DDR2 or DDR3, but since it comes with DDR2 I would get that.

If you wanted to upgrade to 16 GB of RAM you should get (4x4GB) DDR2, and base the MHz speed off of your current RAM sticks.

The specs are listed [here](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-essentio-cg5270-bp003/) from CNET and [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883220034) from Newegg.